# Dict columns extraction using for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a dict named 'data'

```
{
   "error":false,
   "message":"Ok",
   "data":{
      "numFound":1845,
      "start":0,
      "numFoundExact":true,
      "docs":[
         {
            "sub_farmer_id":0,
            "grade_a_produce":320,
            "commodity_image":"red_carrot.jpg",
            "farm_image":"",
            "batch_status":"completed",
            "batch_count":30,
            "franchise_type":"TELF",
            "sr_assignee_id":0,
            "farm_status":"converted",
            "state_name":"RAJASTHAN",
            "farmer_id":1648,
            "grade_a_sell_price":0,
            "id":"11",
            "commodity_name":"Carrot Red",
            "acerage":1,
            "soil_k":0,
            "lgd_state_id":8,
            "soil_n":0,
            "unique_key":"11_8",
            "historic_gdd":0.41,
            "farm_type":"soiless",
            "soil_test_report":"",
            "user_id":1648,
            "expected_yield_delivery_date":"2020-04-30T00:00:00Z",
            "current_gdd":0,
            "soil_p":0,
            "expected_grade_a_produce":636,
            "water_ph":0,
            "end_date":"2020-04-30T00:00:00Z",
            "batch_id":8,
            "expected_delivery_date":"2020-04-30T00:00:00Z",
            "previous_crop_ids":"0",
            "batch_updated_at":"2021-12-29T17:50:58Z",
            "grade_c_rejection":0,
            "water_test_report":"",
            "farm_updated_at":"2021-12-29T17:51:00Z",
            "water_ec":0,
            "start_date":"2019-10-30T00:00:00Z",
            "assignee_id":0,
            "pest_problems":"",
            "expected_production":1060,
            "is_active":true,
            "mobile":"7015150636",
            "grade_b_sell_price":0,
            "irrigation_type":"drip",
            "total_acerage":0,
            "current_pdd":0,
            "commodity_id":68,
            "stage":"flowering",
            "farm_health":"0",
            "expected_grade_b_produce":424,
            "grade_b_produce":740,
            "historic_pdd":0.31,
            "username":"Agritecture",
            "variety_name":"",
            "sr_assignee_name":"",
            "lng":0,
            "locality":"",
            "assignee_name":"",
            "subfarmer_mobile_no":"",
            "commodity_image_96px_icon":"",
            "subfarmer_name":"",
            "batch_end_date":"",
            "lat":0,
            "_version_":1720553030989906000
         }
```

But I am trying to extract data from list and append in a new csv with different columns so that it looks neat and clean

so, Here I am trying code

```
       writer = csv.DictWriter(response_data, fieldnames=['Farmer Name', 'Mobile', 'Irrigation Type', 'Batch Status',
                                                           'Soil Parameters',
                                                           'Water Parameters', 'Crop Name', 'Farm Status', 'Farm Type',
                                                           'Franchise Type', 'Farm Total Acerage', 'Batch Acerage',
                                                           'Farm Health(%)', 'Historical Yield(/Acre)',
                                                           'Expected Produce',
                                                           'Actual Yield(/Acre)', 'Actual Produce', 'Crop health(%)',
                                                           'Stage', 'SOP Adherence', 'Assignee', 'Sub Farmer',
                                                           'Last Activity Update', 'Exp. Delivery Date'], delimiter=",")
        writer.writeheader()

        for docs in data.keys():
            writer.writerow(
                {"Farmer Name": docs.get('username'), "Mobile": docs.get('mobile')
                 "Irrigation Type": data.get('irrigation_type'), "Batch Status": data.get('batch_status'),
                 "Soil Parameters": {'N:-': data.get('soil_n'), 'P:-': data.get('soil_p'),
                                     'K:-': data.get('soil_k')},
                 "Water Parameters": {'ec:-': data.get('water_ec'), 'pH:-': data.get('water_ph'), },
                 "Crop Name": data.get('commodity_name'), "Farm Status": data.get('farm_status'),
                 "Farm Type": data.get('farm_type'),
                 "Franchise Type": data.get('franchise_type'), "Farm Total Acerage": data.get('total_acerage'),
                 "Batch Acerage": data.get('batch_count'), "Farm Health(%)": data.get('farm_health'),
                 "Historical Yield(/Acre)": data.get(''),
                 "Expected Produce": data.get('expected_production'), "Actual Yield(/Acre)": data.get('username'),
                 "Actual Produce": data.get('username'), "Crop health(%)": data.get('username'),
                 "Stage": data.get('stage'),
                 "SOP Adherence": data.get('sope'),
                 "Last Activity Update": data.get('end_date'),
                 "Exp. Delivery Date": data.get('expected_delivery_date')
                 })
```

SO that the data extract from that dict and keep on append on the cdv file as methioned column

But It shows an error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I could not get the columns value in my header from the dict

Comment: replace "docs.get(...)" with "data.get(...)" and it should work.

Comment: I tried the error is TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Your input data is not a dict but a JSON structure (false is JSON, False is Python). Double quotes is not the standard string representation in Python.

Comment: It worked but now also the exported csv file in empty with the headers name only

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it is confusing that you have a dict called `data` which has a key called `"data"`, and that you are iterating over `docs` in a dict with a key called `"docs"`.

However, the error is because you are iterating over `data.keys()`, which returns a string for each value.

An illustrative example:

```
my_dict = {
    "foo" : "bar",
    "baz" : "luhrmann"
}

for each_key in my_dict.keys():
    print(f"{each_key} : {type(each_key)}")
```

This will return:

```
foo : <class 'str'>
baz : <class 'str'>
```

So in the line `docs.get('username')`, you are trying to call the `get` method on a string. The error is telling you that strings do not have this method. I think what you are trying to do is `data['docs'].get('username')`.